# Why are our page-level unique events lower than unique pageviews for the same pages?

Tags: google-analytics

We have GA events set up to fire on load of pages which contain certain internal ad placements.

We are now looking to use these as part of a funnel report created with Google Analytics for GSheets, but are not sure they are reliable, because when you compare these unique events to unique pageviews of the same pages, the events are much lower.

e.g. 10,243 unique events and 14,406 unique pageviews

Can anyone shed any light on this? It was my understanding that since they are both hit level data, firing on page load, they should be broadly in line?

There does not appear to be any issue with our tracking code firing pageviews more than once...

Help appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are filtering down to just the live instances you want to count? (P.S. don't understand why anyone would think GA events don't involve programming - GTM is all about defining logic, and any other way of setting up events involves even more programming.)

Comment: Thank you Mandy.

Yes, because we are using the same logic to filter the pageviews as we have used to set up when the events are triggered in GTM... it seems bizarre at the moment.